# Terminal hangs when installing rb-rmagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm trying to install rb-rmagick and running into some trouble.  The installation stops at "Building rb-rmagick".  I know it takes a while, so I let it run overnight, but still don't see any progress.  I'm running it on a brand new MacBook Pro so speed/memory shouldn't be an issue.

From http://rb-rmagick.darwinports.com/, the instruction says to do `cd /opt/local/bin/portslocation/dports/rb-rmagick` before you run `sudo port install rb-rmagick`, but I don't have the portslocation directory in my bin.

I've installed macPort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out there's actually an error after doing sudo port -v install rb-rmagick. A font file was missing. There are a couple of ways to solve this. trac.macports.org/ticket/19602 has some explanation.